# Dockerfile VOLUME command behavior different on WSL

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume, wsl-2

I have set up docker to work with WSL 2 (running Ubuntu 20.04), following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-containers).
I'm experiencing differences in the behavior when building an image from a Dockerfile.
My example Dockerfile contains the following steps:

```
FROM busybox
VOLUME /foo
RUN touch /foo/bar.txt
```

When running `docker build` on my linux machine (Fedora 33), everything works fine. When running from my WSL machine, I get the following error:

```
> [2/2] RUN touch /foo/bar.txt:
#5 0.221 touch: /foo/bar.txt: No such file or directory
```

It seems like the `VOLUME` command doesn't run (failing step is 2/2 instead of 3/3). I couldn't find any documentation regarding this behavior differences. Is anyone familiar with such differences? Is there some way to avoid them?

Docker versions used -

On Linux native (Fedora 33):

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:19:16 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:16:56 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

On WSL 2 (Ubuntu 20.04):

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.9
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:17:50 2021
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.3
  GitCommit:        269548fa27e0089a8b8278fc4fc781d7f65a939b
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc92
  GitCommit:        ff819c7e9184c13b7c2607fe6c30ae19403a7aff
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Comment: That Dockerfile doesn't make a whole lot of sense, since the most visible effect of `VOLUME` is to prevent following `RUN` instructions from changing that directory; you can almost always safely delete `VOLUME` lines without affecting anything else.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The case here is that calling `VOLUME` is enough to create the directory when building on Linux, but not enough when building on WSL. Removing the `VOLUME` command in this case will not help, since the directory still doesn't exist when the `RUN touch` command is called. I could just call `RUN mkdir /foo` before and solve this, but I want to know if this can be solved without editing the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the two machines was that the WSL machine had BuildKit enabled and the Linux machine didn't.
[BuildKit doesn't apply the `VOLUME` command during build](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/7133), and thus doesn't create the directory if it's no there.

The "correct" solution would be to use `mkdir` directly to create the dir before using it. If that's not possible, another solution would be to disable BuildKit (by doing the opposite of [these instructions](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#to-enable-buildkit-builds)).